# Como fazer um "alert" em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo um formulário de e-mail em PHP, e estou tentando fazer um `alert` quando o cliente for clicar em enviar uma validação.

A validação parece que funciona, pois ele redireciona para a página que eu quero, mas não aparece o `alert`.

Será que está certo este código?

```
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);

echo  "<script>alert('Email enviado com Sucesso!);</script>";

header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: PHP roda no servidor, alert de JS roda no cliente. Seria legal dar uma relida nos conceito básico do que é PHP, servidor web e navegador de internet, para facilitar a lógica ao fazer a programação em si.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O `alert()` não é uma solução boa para mostrar alguma mensagem para o usuário no navegador mas vou responder o que você perguntou:

```
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);
echo "<script type='javascript'>alert('Email enviado com Sucesso!');";
echo "javascript:window.location='index.php';</script>";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/AlertOnMail.php).

Para ver funcionando:

```js
javascript:alert('Email enviado com Sucesso!');
javascript:window.location='index.php';
```

Obviamente simplifiquei, você terá que montar uma página mínima para executar isto.

Answer (score 5):

Sobre o seu código o caso é simples, falta só uma aspas

```
echo  "<script>alert('Email enviado com Sucesso!');</script>";
```

Beleza?

Answer (score 4):

Uma possível solução, que mescla as propostas das outras respostas, é montar um HTML mínimo, mas usando um META para o refresh levar alguns segundos sem atrapalhar o ALERT:

```
<?php
   mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);
   echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
   echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
   echo '<head>';
   echo '   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/index.php">';
   echo '</head>';
   echo '<body onload="alert('+"'"+'Email enviado com Sucesso!'+"'"+');">';
   echo '<a href="http://example.com/index.php">click!</a>';
   echo '</body>';
   echo '</html>';
?>
```

Você pode remover a tag `<a>`, mas nestes casos é interessante manter, para que caso haja um problema no *refresh*, o usuário não fique sem saber o que fazer.

Agora, eu acho MUITO melhor uma coisa mais simples. Já que é pra montar um HTML, avise na própria página:

```
<?php
   mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);
   echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
   echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
   echo '<head>';
   echo '   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://example.com/index.php">';
   echo '</head>';
   echo '<body>';
   echo '<p>Seu email foi enviado com sucesso.</p>';
   echo '<a href="http://example.com/index.php">Prosseguir</a>';
   echo '</body>';
   echo '</html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ao invés de utilizar o alert, você poderia fazer de uma outra forma. Caso o e-mail seja enviado corretamente, uma div com a classe CSS "sucesso" aparecerá informando o envio e os campos do formulário limpos após o envio. Caso ocorra algum erro, aparece uma div com a classe "erro" informando que não foi possível o envio do mesmo.

Ficaria algo parecido com isto:

```
<?php

if ($_POST)
{
    $envioEmail = mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);

    if ($envioEmail)
    {
    ?>
        <div class="sucesso">E-mail enviado com sucesso!</div>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <div class="erro">Erro no envio do e-mail.</div>
    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);

header("location:javascript:alert(\"Email enviado com Sucesso!\");location.href=\"index.php\";");
```

E analisando seu código, percebi que você quer execurtar javascript sem mesmo abrir a tag javascript:

Então você pode tentar também:

```
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);

echo "<script>alert('Email enviado com Sucesso!);</script>";

header('location: index.php');
```

E isso faria com que o header não podesse ser executado, pois se você quiser usar o header você teria que colocar ele antes de enviar qualquer resposta....

Então experimente usar o rediricionamento dentro do script

```
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);

echo "<script>alert('Email enviado com Sucesso!);location.href=\"index.php\";</script>";
```

Comment: dessa maneira nao rolou ;/

Comment: Dei uma editada, olha só....

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio olha e ver se funcionou....

Comment: Opa, cara ainda não funcionou, o código com o alert ele redireciona para o index, mas nao aparece sem o alert.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma validação no formulário:

```
<script>

function checar()
{
  If (form.qualquercoisa.nome.value=="")
{
   alerta("preencher o campo");
}
else
{
  function enderecoform();
}
```

Faz uma função para checar o endereço e depois uma para checar o e-mail.

Se no final tudo der ok, você faz um `alert` para confirmar o redirecionamento com:

```
alert("sua página será redirecionada");
window.location("endereço da página");
```

Ex.

```
<Form name="qualquer coisa"action="arquivo php" onSubmit="return função checar();">

nome<input type ="texto" name ="nome">
nome<input type ="texto" name ="endeco">
nome<input type ="texto" name ="e-mail">
<Input type ="button">Enviar<\button>
```