# Exibir avisos com PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uns scripts para uma loja e desejo ajudar com alertas, ou melhor, mensagens que serão exibidas após processamento dos formulários. Quero algo mais do tipo atual, seria possível em PHP? Alguém ajuda?

```
header("location:" . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
-> O AVISO/MENSAGEM SERIA AQUI <-
exit;
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar JavaScript?

Comment: Podes enviar o formulário em ajax e receber o retorno por json informando uma mensagem, isso também é javascript.

Comment: hoje ao me cadastrar aqui no site ele mostrou uma aviso no topo, uma barra laranja com uma frase: Conclua o registro para sua conta (X), isso me ajudaria.

Answer (score -3):

Tipo Atual... Jquery plugin gritter, muito prático:

[Veja aqui](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/)

[E aqui](http://boedesign.com/demos/gritter/)

Chama o plugin assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">google.load('jquery', '1.5');</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>'
```

Depois usa assim:

```
$.gritter.add( { title: 'Atenção!', text: 'Erro ao executar tarefa no servidor!', time: 7000, class_name: 'gritter-light', image: '/img/erro.png', });
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Comment: Estaa tentando fazer isso, mas como sou novo aqui não sabia direito como comentar com código, o comentario anterior ficou meio bagunçado, vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Clique no botão [edit] e coloque no corpo da sua resposta

Comment: Transpus seu comentário para o corpo da sua resposta, veja o que pode melhorar.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, não seria o caso de apenas fazer um `alert()` usando o JS mesmo?

Comment: Corrigi o código, por que perdi tantos pontos desse jeito? Não é só um alert, conforme a pergunta ele quer algo diferente!!

Comment: Na verdade eu não entendo muito das linguagens em questão, eu perguntei justamente para tentar entender. Eu acho que sobre os pontos perdidos é por talvez haver alguma confusão no entendimento da pergunta.

Comment: Se não entende das linguagens em questão, como afirmar que houve confusão? O que faltou pra mim foi conhecimento do uso da ferramenta do fórum e não do uso das linguagens e da resposta que foi corrida. Quem tira esses pontos de forma tão arbitrária assim?

Comment: @Aragão votos negativos são feitos por diferentes usuários, cada uma das pessoas que negativou pode ter tido um motivo diferente, posso lhe dar umas dicas? O motivo da maioria ter negativado (estes votos não foram arbitrários) Independente do seu código está certo no funcionamento dele, o correto seria explicar o uso do redirecionamento combinado ao um `alert`, o que você fez foi apenas dar uma alternativa ao `alert`, outra coisa, não somos um fórum, o StackOverflow é uma plataforma de Q&A, pergunta e resposta, então geralmente a resposta tem ser ao problema que o autor está enfrentando...

Comment: ... Que no caso é um problema de trabalhar códigos backend com frontend. Eu acho que este é o motivo de tantos votos negativos, é normal acontecer este tipo de coisa, os votos negativos não são malignos eles apenas expressam opiniões. Espero que entenda a plataforma da comunidade e talvez refaça a sua resposta (se bem que não recomendo, pois esta pergunta é uma clara duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54345/3635 e por este motivo não vale muito a pena responder). Seja bem vindo @Aragão, participe, com o tempo irá entender o funcionamento do Q&A StackOverflow e ...

Comment: ... não vai conseguir usar outro tipo de comunidade