# Qual a boa solução para substituir o alert?

Tags: javascript, ux

Em uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54345/como-fazer-um-alert-em-php), de como fazer o `alert`, tem uma resposta, a mais votada, que diz:

> O alert não é uma solução boa para mostrar alguma mensagem para o usuário no navegador mas vou responder o que você perguntou...

Qual seria a solução boa para mostrar alguma mensagem para o usuário então?

Comment: Um modal que se assemelha a um alert, por que o alert é meio "sem graça" e além de ser definido pelo navegador o seu design. Modal tipo esse exemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NePR0BQf3VmKtuMmhVR7?p=preview

Comment: Olha, existem N ferramentas para gerar alerts "mais bonitos", tais como o SweetAlert. O problema do alert, na minha opinião, é que ele é feio para o usuário final.

Comment: Toda vez que alguém disser que a solução mais simples de todas, nativa da linguagem e implementada universalmente em todos os navegadores não é uma boa solução, sugira a essa pessoa que procure um psicólogo. Ela provavelmente sofre da [Síndrome do Não-Inventado-Aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A3o_Inventado_Aqui).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mensagem deveria ser apresentada na própria página, de preferência perto do dado que originou o erro, com destaque, talvez temporariamente e de forma que não obstrua o uso normal da página. E este era o espírito da resposta, posso te garantir :)

[image: Mensagem de erro]

Claro que tem exceções. Pode haver alguma caso que abrir um modela de alerta padrão do navegador pode ser mais adequado. Mas esta é uma prática considerada antiga e pouco amigável.

Mesmo nestes caso onde um modal é o mais indicado hoje é considerado mais apresentável fazer uma janela dentro da página com um visual condizente com o resto da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PHP é uma tecnologia de *backend* então faz pouca diferença a forma como é apresentado para o usuário. No *frontend* é possível criar uma experiência para o usuário da forma que desejar. Isso é feito com JavaScript, HTML, CSS. Note que a pergunta original estava falando em JavaScript, não PHP. O PHP nem sabe o que está rodando no cliente.

Tem uma quantidade infinita de jeitos de fazer isto, pesquisando aqui no SOpt já acha vários ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20mensagem%20de%20alerta) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20mensagem%20de%20erro)).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

é possivel criar o alert em javascript pelo php, so que não necessarimente sera criado pelo php, isso porque o php não é executado na maquina cliente e sim no servidor gerando o codigo HTML (js e css) para o cliente

```
<?php
   echo "<script>alert('bem vindo ao site');</script>";
?>
```

não é muito recomendado passar uma mensagem pelo alert, isso é o proprio usuario consegue desativar o alert, então pode acontecer dele não receber a sua mensagem na segunda vez, uma forma de contornar isso seria uma parte oculta na pagina com a mensagem, exemplo um div

```
<div id="kodomsg" style="display: none">
senha invalida
</div>
```

quando voce precisar exibir aquela mensagem basta simplesmente exibir ela, pode usar o JS para fazer isso de forma dinamica

```
<script>
   var minhamsg = document.getElementById("kodomsg");
   minhamsg.style.display = "block"; //"none" para ocultar
</script>
```

voce pode criar uma função para exibir/ocultar e chamar ela por um evento especifico, exemplo assim que apertar um botão

```
<div id="kodomsg" style="display: none">
era uma vez um botão ... fim da historia
</div> 
<input type="button" value="aperte" onclick="kodofun()">
<script>
function kodofun(){
   var minhamsg = document.getElementById("kodomsg");
   minhamsg.style.display = "block"; //"none" para ocultar
}
</script>
```

não necessariamente precisa ser estatico voce pode alterar a propria mensagem dinamicamente por JS tambem

```
<div id="kodomsg" style="display: none">
senha invalida
</div>
<script>
   var minhamsg = document.getElementById("kodomsg");
   minhamsg.innerHTML = "essa é a nova msg";
</script>
```

voce pode inclusive criar uma coisa parecida com alert, deixar o div flutuando sobrepondo a pagina com um botão para fechar ele usando js e css, inclusive pode customizar ele da forma que desejar

```
<style>
#kodomsg{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
}
</style>

<div id="kodomsg">
bem vindo ao site<br>
<input type="button" value="fechar" onclick="kodofechar()">
</div> 

<script>
function kodofechar(){
   var minhamsg = document.getElementById("kodomsg");
   minhamsg.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tem muitas formas interessantes de fazer isso como tambem existem muitas aplicações para isso ^^ (ps: esse meu exemplo fico feio pra caramba kkk)